# What happens when I return a Future from a function marked as async in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-async

Consider this example:

```
Future<int> doAsyncThing() => new Future.value(42);

usingAsync() async => doAsyncThing();

main() {
  var thing = usingAsync();
  // what is the runtimeType of thing ?
}
```

What is the runtimeType of the object returned by `usingAsync()` ? Would it be `Future<Future<int>>` or `Future<int>` or something else ?

Answer (score 8):

The return type of `usingAsync()` is technically `dynamic` because there is no return type annotation given for `usingAsync()`. Omitting a return type annotation is the same as using `dynamic` for the return type annotation.

The runtimeType of the object returned by `usingAsync()` is `Future<dynamic>`. Functions marked with `async` simply always return a `Future<dynamic>` object.

When the Future from `usingAsync()` completes, it "flattens" its contained Future, and completes with an `int`.

```
import 'dart:async';

Future<int> doAsyncThing() => new Future.value(42);

usingAsync() async => doAsyncThing();

main() {
  var thing = usingAsync();

  // what is the runtimeType of thing ?
  print(thing.runtimeType); // Future

  thing.then((value) {
    print(value);  // 42
    print(value.runtimeType);  // int
  });
}
```

The author of the code sample in the original question probably wants to write:

```
Future<int> usingAsync() async => await doAsyncThing();
```

Or, even cleaner:

```
Future<int> usingAsync() => doAsyncThing();
```

That is, if your function returns a Future, you might not need to mark your function as async. Just return the Future.

See it in action: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/73fed0857efab196e3f9

Comment: Will the second version "Future<int> usingAsync() => doAsyncThing();
" do the await automatically?

Comment: So what's the difference between `Future<int> doAsyncThing() async => new Future.value(42);` and `Future<int> doAsyncThing() => new Future.value(42);`? Is it the exact same thing?